# I can't call the modal component in other component correctly on React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

i'm trying call a modal component in other component in my aplication, when I click on de button to open de modal, its work fine, but when I click to close the modal or when I click in the "ok" to close the modal it doesn't work. I'm using Antd to do this, I dont know what I'm doing wrong, If you can help me, I will be very grateful. Thank you !

My Menu component where I call my modal component

```
import React from "react";
import { Layout, Menu, Button } from "antd";
import css from "./index.module.css";
import imgLogo from "./../../Assets/logo_blue_full.png";

import CartContext from "./../../CartContext";
import CartIcon from "./../../CartIcon";
import ModalApp from "./../Modal/index";

const { Header } = Layout;

class MenuAntd extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      visible: false
    };
  }

  showModal = () => {
    this.setState({
      visible: true
    });
  };


  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Header className={css.borderMenu}>
          <Menu theme="dark" style={{ lineHeight: "64px" }}>
            <img className={css.imagemLogo} src={imgLogo} alt="logo" />

            <Menu.Item key="1">Cursos</Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key="2">Cadastre-se</Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key="3" onClick={this.showModal}>Entrar</Menu.Item>
          </Menu>
        </Header>

        <ModalApp visible={this.state.visible} />

      </>
    );
  }
}

MenuAntd.contextType = CartContext;

export default MenuAntd;
```

My Modal component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import {  Modal } from "antd";

class ModalApp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  }

  handleCancel = () => {
    this.setState({
      visible: false
    });
  };

  handleOk = () => {
    this.setState({
      visible: false
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Modal
          title="My Modal"
          visible={this.props.visible}
          onOk={this.handleOk}
          onCancel={this.handleCancel}
        >
          <p>Some contents...</p>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ModalApp;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your setState handling the modal needs to be in the component where the state is stored.

```
import React from "react";
import { Layout, Menu, Button } from "antd";
import css from "./index.module.css";
import imgLogo from "./../../Assets/logo_blue_full.png";

import CartContext from "./../../CartContext";
import CartIcon from "./../../CartIcon";
import ModalApp from "./../Modal/index";

const { Header } = Layout;

class MenuAntd extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      visible: false
    };
  }

  handleModal = (status) => {
    this.setState({
      visible: status
    });
  };


  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Header className={css.borderMenu}>
          <Menu theme="dark" style={{ lineHeight: "64px" }}>
            <img className={css.imagemLogo} src={imgLogo} alt="logo" />
            <Menu.Item key="1">Cursos</Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key="2">Cadastre-se</Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item 
              key="3" 
              onClick={() => this.handleModal(true)}
            >
              Entrar
            </Menu.Item>
          </Menu>
        </Header>

        <ModalApp 
          visible={this.state.visible}
          handleModal={this.handleModal}
        />

      </>
    );
  }
}

MenuAntd.contextType = CartContext;

export default MenuAntd;
```

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import {  Modal } from "antd";

class ModalApp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Modal
          title="My Modal"
          visible={this.props.visible}
          onOk={() => this.props.handleModal(false)}
          onCancel={() => this.props.handleModal(false)}
        >
          <p>Some contents...</p>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ModalApp;
```